# How to fetch data from yaml file

Tags: ansible, yaml

For some reason I can't figure this out. I am using Ansible and a YAML file full of data. I want to be able to grab a specific value based on a value that I already have.

data.yml

```
persons:
  - name: Jack
    hair_color: Black

  - name: Jill 
    hair_color: Blonde
```

I want to grab Jack's hair color. In my playbook I tried the following:

```
- name: import data file
  include_vars: 
    file: data.yml
    name: data

- debug:
    msg: "{{ data.persons[0].hair_color }}"
```

The above works and returns back "Black", but this is not how I want to fetch the data. I want to use the name Jack to be able to get his hair color. So something along the lines of:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ data.persons['name=Jack'].hair_color }}"
```

The above obviously does not work.

Comment: => `{{ (data.persons | selectattr('name', '==', 'Jack') | first).hair_color }}`

Comment: => `{{ (data.persons | items2dict(key_name='name', value_name='hair_color')).Jack }}`

Comment: Great - both answers work for my need. Thank you!

Comment: Note that any of the above solutions takes for granted there's a single Jack in your dictionary list. If there are several, you'll get the hair color of first or last parsed depending on your choice of expression.

Comment: ^-- where the code proposed by @Zeitounator have the advantage to be expandable, in the case of multiple Jacks, to return an list of hair colours via `{{ data.persons | selectattr('name', '==', 'Jack') | map(attribute='hair_color') }}` which would return something like `['Black', 'Brown', 'Gray']`

Comment: Given both solutions, would it be possible to do the following: 

`
- name: Create var
  set_fact:
    a: "persons"

{{ (data.{{ a }} | selectattr('name', '==', 'Jack') | first).hair_color }}
`

The above does not work and I've tried other ways to use a variable inside another variable without any luck

Answer (score 1):

Ofc, the answers provided in the comments are already correct.
I'm just showing another way of doing it, via a loop:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.hair_color }}"
  loop: "{{ persons }}"
  when: item.name == 'Jack'
```

Ansible returns `Black`.